# How to access an element of a multidimensional array by a key that is in another linear array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

We have a multidimensional associative array. It is necessary to address to an element of an array on a key which is written down in other linear array.

That is, there is a multidimensional data array and a linear array with a key:

```
$a=[
  'animals'=> [
    'cats' => [
      'catusdomesticus' => 'home',
      'pantera' => 'wild'
    ]
  ]
];

$keys=['animals', 'cats', 'pantera'];
```

There are two things to do:

1. (simple) Get the value of $a['animals']['cats']['pantera']
2. (complex) Delete the element $a['animals']['cats']['pantera']

How to do this in PHP5?

Note: It is required to do without code generation and eval ().

**UPD:**

Get value is easy:

```
$item =& $a;
foreach($keys as $key)
  $item =& $item[$key];
var_dump( $item );
```

For remove element i try next code:

```
$item =& $a;
for($i=0; $i<count($keys); $i++)
{
  $item =& $item[$keys[$i]];

  if($i===count($keys)-1) {
    echo "\nDelete element:\n";
    var_dump($item);

    unset($item);
  }
}
var_dump( $a );
```

But this is not work. The unset() by reference to array value cant remove array element.

**UPD2:**

Short solution for set value or remove element from array:

```
$item =&$a;
foreach($keys as $key) {
  $array =& $item;
  $item =& $item[$key];
}
$array[$key] = 42; // For set value
OR
unset($array[$key]); // For remove element
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the key `catusdomesticus` be in the new array? Is there a reason?

Comment: What have you tried? 1. You must try it by yourself 2. If something is wrong you come here and ask us for help. 3. Good luck!

Comment: @Tobias F, the structure of the array is unknown beforehand. It has unlimited nesting depth, and unlimited sibling elements.

Comment: @MateiMihai, see update

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_value($keys, $a)
{
    foreach($keys as $k)
    {
       if (isset($a[$k])
       {
            if (is_array($a[$k]))
            {
                return get_value($keys, $a[$k]);
            }
            else
            {
                return $a[$k];
            }
       }
    }

    return null; //nothing found
}
```

Comment: +1 For the recursive approach!! I was writing something similar as a morning warm-up exercise, but U were faster.

Comment: when you answer a question you should add a brief description of what it does and why, the goal it to help people learn from the answer not just give them code.

Comment: This is answer to simple question. How about to remove element?

Answer (score 0):

here are two methods, I'm assuming the second method will address you issue best.

```
<?php

$a=[
  'animals'=> [
    'cats' => [
      'catusdomesticus' => 'home',
      'pantera' => 'wild'
    ]
  ]
];

$keys=['animals', 'cats', 'pantera'];

//Method 1, excplicitly say which associative values you want
echo $a[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]];
echo "<br/>";

//Method 2 use a loop and keep going down
$holder = $a;
foreach($keys as $key){
    $holder=$holder[$key];
}
echo $holder;

?>
```

Comment: Method 1 is incorrect. This code depends on keys array size. How to you make if get 

`$keys=['animals', 'cats']?`

Comment: And how to use Method 2 for delete element?

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the array value using reference with a small tweak

```
$a=[    
  'animals'=> [ 
    'cats' => [ 
      'catusdomesticus' => 'home',  
      'pantera' => 'wild'   
    ]   
  ] 
];  

$keys=['animals', 'cats', 'pantera'];   

$delItem = &$a; 

foreach($keys as $key=>$val){   
  if($key == count($keys)-1)    
      $lastKey = $val;  
  else  
      $delItem = &$delItem[$val];   

}   
echo $delItem[$lastKey];//Get Value 
unset($delItem[$lastKey]);//Remove Value    
print_r($a);`
```